# StringTemplate: Loading a Template from disk?

Tags: c#, .net, stringtemplate

I am using StringTemplate in c# and following code to load a template from a subdirectory of my application.

```
StringTemplateGroup group = new StringTemplateGroup("myGroup", "/tmp");
StringTemplate query = group.GetInstanceOf("Sample");
query.SetAttribute("column", "name");
Console.WriteLine(query);
```

I have a template file Sample.st in the tmp directory of my application.

I am getting the following error.

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.ArgumentException: Can't find
>   template Sample.st; group hierarchy is
>   [myGroup]

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: http://www.stringtemplate.org/

Comment: I am having the same problem as you on one machine but not on another. Have you figured it out?

Comment: @randy: I used absolute path. Although I did not like to use the absolute path.

Comment: I resolved my issue by including a reference to the Antlr3.Runtime.Debug assembly.

Comment: See my answer below; you don't need to add a reference to the debug assembly, just the plain Antlr3.Runtime.dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you should specify absolute path as a second parameter for `StringTemplateGroup` constructor?

Comment: Is it possible to load the template from an embedded file inside an assembly?

Comment: See section "Loading Templates relative to the Assembly's Location" here: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST/Defining+Templates

Comment: Unfortunately even after giving the Absolute path I am unable to load the template.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding a reference to the Antlr3.StringTemplate assembly, you ALSO need to add a reference to the Antlr3.Runtime assembly (not necessarily the Antlr3.Runtime.Debug assembly, although this would also work). This worked for me.